# Reading a file's name from a text field and displaying it

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a program that reads a file name through a text field and displays it in a text area. I will also need a clear button. This is what I have so far:

```
private void enterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String fileName = jTextField1.getText();
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jTextArea1.setText(s + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        jTextArea1.setText("File not found!");
    }
}

private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextArea1.setText("");
}
```

For some reason, it is not reading my text file on my desktop, called "hi". How could I make my program work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it not reading the contents of the file, or is the file not found?

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Catch `FileNotFoundException` separately from the general `IOException`. Write a message _and_ `e.printStackTracke()` while you are developing.

Answer (score 3):

`setText` does that, sets the text of the field

Now, `JTextArea` has a simple `read` method for reading content, for example

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/New Text Document.txt")))) {
    textArea.read(reader, "File");
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your problem but this seems not right to me and I want to mention to you to fix it:

Actually what you do is putting the last line of text in your textArea1 and if your last line is "\n" or an empty line, then obviously you don't see anything on your screen.

It would be good to use StringBuffer to store your lines which are read from the file and display the whole text. The following code can help you:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(s).append('\n');
    }
jTextArea1.setText(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: If you're going to read the file a line at a time, instead of all at once as @MadProgrammer shows, you should prefer the unsynchronized `StringBuilder` over the old, synchronized `StringBuffer` - but why bother with either? JTextArea as an [`.append(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 0):

your code is actually working and it is reading the file, but your code goes wrong inside the while loop when you are assigning the value you are not concating string inside the while loop i have made some changes to your code try this one.

```
String fileName = "src/hi.txt";
         String content = "";
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String s;      
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
       content+="\n"+s;

    }
        System.out.println(content);

    br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
}
```

Comment: oops :D made the changes sorry

Comment: You're risking have the file left open and leaking resources, you shouldn't be closing the resources within the try block but in the finally block, but you could use try with resources instead